# command train_test_split - error 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, train-test-split

I'm trying to split data into sets: `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, `y_test` using the `train_test_split()` command. Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data
```

Below is the program code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_array = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]])
target_array = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14])

array1 = {'data': data_array, 'target': target_array}

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(
array1.data, array1.target)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1.data` is not how you get dict value in Python.

Correct syntax is

```
array1["data1"]
```

Comment: what the data should look like to be able to use this command: X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(
array1.data, array1.target)

Comment: `array1` should be an object of the class which has `data` and `target` attributes. You can look up this tutorial on this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects